# SailsJs: Unknown properties are generated while Model.find().exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have written a service function in api/services/SomeServices.js

```
  getCreditDebitNotes:function(vid){
    console.log('resolving credit and debits');
    var deferred=sails.q.defer();
    CreditDebitNotes.find({vendorID:vid,status:1},{select:['soid','statementID','amount']})
      .exec(function(err,creditDebitNotes){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          return deferred.reject(err);
        }
        console.log('array of creditDebitNotes:');
        console.log(creditDebitNotes);
        for(var key in creditDebitNotes[0]){
          console.log(key);
        }
        console.log('Magic happened');
        deferred.resolve(creditDebitNotes);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  },
```

I am getting some unknown keys on console while looping through the object.See in attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looping through the object it will return all the listed properties. Hence you are getting toJson,constructor etc... along with the required properties. Use hasOwnProperty to eliminate those inherited ones.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict additional property formation while model.find()..
(Restrict inheritance)!